# Inequality Involving Complex Norm

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, inequality

I am trying to prove, that for any real $x$ and any real $t \neq 0$ that
$$\bigg{|}\frac{e^{itx}-1}{t}\bigg{|} \leq |x| $$
Graphically it seems to be true but I cant quite get it formally.

Comment: Hint: $e^{itx}-1=2ie^{-itx/2}\sin\frac12tx$

Answer (score 0):

Use $\frac{e^{itx}-1}{itx}=e^{itx/2}\operatorname{sinc}\tfrac{tx}{2}$ and $|\operatorname{sinc}z|\le1$ for $z\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

With $f(t) = e^{ixt}$, the mean value theorem gives
$|f(t)-f(0)| \le \max_{z \in [0,t]} |f'(z)| |t-0|$.

Since $|f'(z)| = |x|$ we have $|f(t)-f(0)| = |e^{ixt} -1| \le |x||t|$